# jquery post with $.ajax, how to avoid multiple post?

Tags: php, jquery, http-post

still looking for a solution but not find yet, I have a function to manage different forms on same/differents pages

```
function formStantardAction(correctAnswer,addCustomData){
        addCustomData = (typeof addCustomData == "undefined")?'':addCustomData;
    correctAnswer = (typeof correctAnswer == "undefined")?'Saved.':correctAnswer;
    $('form.standard').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var modalWin = $(this).parent();
        var values = $('form.standard').serialize() + addCustomData;
        $.ajax({
        url: "inc/gateway.php",
        data: values,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){
            if (data == "OK"){
                $(modalWin).html(correctAnswer).delay(500).fadeOut(500);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    mw_close();
                }, 1000);
            }else{
                alert(data);
            }
        }
        });

    });
    }
```

after loaded the page and form with an input type="button" named SEND

```
$('form.standard [name="SEND"]').click(function(){
            var str = $('#sortableTo').serializelist();
        formStantardAction('New train inserted.',str);
            $('form.standard').submit();
        });
```

all the values reach a php page via POST that made all the things (validating, insert in db, update log...) and answer with 'OK' if all OK (so the form in the modal window is substituted with custom message and fade out) or... if there is an error, php answer with some text that js popups with an alert keeping the modal window open with the form.

It's all ok BUT, if php answer with an error, with second click of button SEND the post is sent 2 times. 
And if I make another error on second send, and click again the send button, the post values is sent three time... and so on.

What can I do? Where is my error?

thanks.

Comment: Not sure if this will make a difference but if running the post asynchronous is causing the issue try setting `async: false` on the ajax settings and see if this will make a difference.

Comment: just try to add return false after your setTimeout function and see if stops it.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Hi, thanks for suggestions but just try, nothing changes.

Comment: @RavinderSingh thanks for suggestion but try to add return false inside SUCCESS, inside wrong answer, at the end of fucntion (after $.ajax) but make the same error

Comment: @keebOo: Sorry it didn't work but that is why I only added it as a comment cause I wasn't sure. I'm glad you got it sorted out in the end :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try excluding submit block:

```
 function formStantardAction(correctAnswer,addCustomData){
        addCustomData = (typeof addCustomData == "undefined")?'':addCustomData;
    correctAnswer = (typeof correctAnswer == "undefined")?'Saved.':correctAnswer;
    //$('form.standard').submit(function(event){
     //   event.preventDefault();
//change 'this' to form.standard
        var modalWin = $('form.standard').parent();
        var values = $('form.standard').serialize() + addCustomData;
        $.ajax({
        url: "inc/gateway.php",
        data: values,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){
            if (data == "OK"){
                $(modalWin).html(correctAnswer).delay(500).fadeOut(500);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    mw_close();
                }, 1000);
            }else{
                alert(data);
            }
        }
        });

    });
   // }
```

and after loaded page:

```
   $('form.standard [name="SEND"]').click(function(){
                var str = $('#sortableTo').serializelist();
            formStantardAction('New train inserted.',str);
//excluding submit event
               // $('form.standard').submit();
            });
```

Because $.ajax {} with type:"Post" is already a submit process and then when script call submit then it re-submit.

Hope this right and help

Comment: YES YES YES! :) (the submit function was for manage also the form without custom buttons and only with submit button... but I'll add a new piece of code) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possbile that somewhere in your code you bind the submit event to the form everytime you get the data back from the ajax-request?

I can't check this in the code you submitted here.

Comment: mmmmm... I make a check, this could be more close to the answer. take a look at the last lines of code, after the main function: each time I click the button 1) I get the values of form 2) write again the submit function 3) submit the form  ....could be this the error?

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable as flag

```
var flag = 0;
```

and check this flag while posting and reset it after completed

```
function formStantardAction(correctAnswer,addCustomData){
       **if(flag == 1){
           return false;
       }
       flag = 1;**
        addCustomData = (typeof addCustomData == "undefined")?'':addCustomData;
    correctAnswer = (typeof correctAnswer == "undefined")?'Saved.':correctAnswer;
    $('form.standard').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var modalWin = $(this).parent();
        var values = $('form.standard').serialize() + addCustomData;
        $.ajax({
        url: "inc/gateway.php",
        data: values,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){
           **flag = 0;**
            if (data == "OK"){
                $(modalWin).html(correctAnswer).delay(500).fadeOut(500);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    mw_close();
                }, 1000);
            }else{
                alert(data);
            }
        }
        });

    });
    }
```

Comment: as before. the question is that is always SUCCESS, with the 'OK' answer and with the 'ERROR' answer, but in case of error the form stay open and when I click SEND button send two time... (get back two time the error from php)

Comment: You can make flag = 0 on error also like success jquery ajax have error

Answer (score 0):

I put some custom code at the beginning of your submit function - basically if a submit is in progress nothing should be done, but otherwise return an error message as usual.

```
var submitting = false; //initialise the variable, this needs to be out of the function!
function formStantardAction(correctAnswer,addCustomData){
    addCustomData = (typeof addCustomData == "undefined")?'':addCustomData;
correctAnswer = (typeof correctAnswer == "undefined")?'Saved.':correctAnswer;

$('form.standard').submit(function(event){
    if (submitting) {
        return false; //if a submit is in progress, prevent further clicks from doing anything
    } else {
        submitting = true; //no submit in progress, but let's make one now
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    var modalWin = $(this).parent();
    var values = $('form.standard').serialize() + addCustomData;
    $.ajax({
    url: "inc/gateway.php",
    data: values,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data){
        if (data == "OK"){
            $(modalWin).html(correctAnswer).delay(500).fadeOut(500);
            setTimeout(function() {
                mw_close();
            }, 1000);
        }else{
            alert(data);
        }
    }
    });

});
}
```

Comment: Sorry... I'm not understand, I mean... 1) click the SEND button 2) Get the current form values + some custom values set by user 3) call the main function to change the data and SUBMIT action of the form, open ajax connection and wai answer 4) put the data on DB and answer OK or answer with error and wait new send .......   where I put submitting true?